# removing last character from knockout observable

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable..

```
this.mytextbox=ko.observable("Daily");
```

I wish to remove the last character on button press.

I tried the following-

```
this.removesinglechar=function(){
               self.mytextbox().substring(0, self.mytextbox().length - 1);
          }
```

as well as `self.mytextbox().slice(0, -1);`

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach works great, but you forgot to actually set the observable. (using `self.mytextbox(theCodeThatReturnsTheNewString)`)

```js
var VM = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  this.label = ko.observable("A long string");
  this.removeLastChar = function() {
    self.label(self.label().slice(0, self.label().length - 1));
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div>
  <span data-bind="text: label"></span><button data-bind="click:removeLastChar">-1</button>
</div>
```